# How to workaround Chrome column-width bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Chrome has a bug that seems unlikely to get fixed anytime soon:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178369

Basically it happens that Chrome can't handle column widths correctly if the cells themselves contain "width=100%" elements.

I need the 100% width elements in the cells.

Does anybody know a workaround for that bug?

Testcase:

```
<table style="width: 800px; border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid blue">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100%; background: red;">
                        1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100%; background: green;">
                        2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wonder if you can just use 99.99%.  I realize it's not really a fix, but is it close enough for your use?

Comment: I just experimented and the bug persists with any value of "width"

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding

```
table-layout: fixed
```

for the outer table should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/ysqx6j4t/

Comment: I already tried that, but then I get overlappings. Also I would like to use "minimum-width" columns - those are impossible with table-layout: fixed

Comment: What do you mean by minimum width columns in this case? Your example had the table width set to 800px fixed, and both sub-tables to 100% – that looks quite rigid to me. If you want “fluidity” somewhere in there, then you should describe the desired behavior more clearly.

Comment: By "minimum width" I mean that the column should take as little space as needed to display it's contents. (The column right to the green cell is such a column - if you put any content in there it will be displayed with as little space as needed, but not more because the width=100% column in the same table will greedily take up all unused space.)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Chrome ignores td style widths unless they are set in very first row of a table. (IE used to do that about 15 years ago.)

So you can't have a single td and colspan=n in first row.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance for this being a response and not answer...

It seems that the bug has now infected not only Chrome, but also newer versions of Opera and Vivaldi.  None of these work-around suggestions work with Chrome, Vivaldi, Opera (newer releases!), even if  style widths are set in the first row, and especially if any column in that first row has a 'min-width' set -- a greedy (ie 100% is ignored).
Setting a column width to 100% so that is 'greedy' DOES work in all versions of Firefox (all the way back to version 3.5!). It also works in Opera 12 (!) but not Opera 65 -- [which shows that just copying someone else's code is not always productive.]

---

An aHA moment -->
The actual bug is this:
If a cell (in any column, not necessarily the first col in the first row) spans multiple columns, and attempts to force the colspan to be greedy, that ends up being applied to the first column ONLY - not to the group.: 
So,

```
<!-- EXAMPLE 0 -->
...
<tr >
<td colspan=4>
<td colspan=8>
     <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100% style="font-size:11pt;">
     <tr style="font-size:8pt;">
         <td width=100%><hr>
         <td class=pnote>&nbsp;SYNOPSIS / EXAMPLE</tr>

     <tr ><!-- THIS IS WHERE IT WENT WRONG IF THE CELL
                  had any markup in addition to colspan=2 -->
          <td colspan=2><b>layerinfo = </b>App.Do (Environment, 'ReturnLayerProperties', {})

          <!-- another solution is to encapsulate everything in this row/cell in another table ...
          <td colspan=2><table width=100%...
                        </table>
          -->     

     <tr style="font-size:8pt;">
         <td width=100%><hr>
         <td class=pnote>&nbsp;RETURNS</tr>

     <tr >
         <td width=100% nowrap><b>layerinfo : &nbsp;{</b>
         <td class=pnote>&nbsp;</td>
     ...
     </table></tr>
```

And the result now is correct [(a) the

---

and the label no longer split the row equally, nor (b) the text on the spanned cell no longer defines the width
of the first column of the table. (wierd, but it happened)[image: ]]